# Can't install Valgrind on Windows

Tags: cmd, valgrind

I'm trying to install Valgrind but after cd to the directory of the source, every time I try to use ./configure I get that "." is not recognized an internal or external command..

Can anyone help?

Edit: The question here is different than that asking about other substitute for Valgrind, my question was specific to how to write the commands on cmd!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I'm convinced that it is not designed for Windows platform. There are some others do the same for Windows as well...

Comment: You could tell _what_ other tools are there for Windows. I know some commercial solutions but I am interested if you found a free tool, preferably as easy and useful as Valgrind.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

`/` is the switch character. `.` Can be several things. Change to `.\configure`. However `.\configure` is the exact same as `configure`.

Windows will try and make sense of WRONG paths. But as commands get more complicated it assumes you are doing it right.

```
. (win.ini) the LAST dot in a file path separates the name from extension

. (dir .\*.txt) the current directory
```

Comment: But do you think that Valgrind can be used on windows in the first place? The more I research about it the more Im convinced that it is not

Comment: The home page makes no mention of Windows.